.NET 8 blazor wasm hot reload not working
Context: Visual Studio 2022 v17.9.6, .NET 8 (SDK v8.0.204), Blazor Webassembly Hosted solution.
Applying Hot Reload to a non-debugging (CTRL-F5 run) webassembly app ... stopped working. At one time in the past it was working (more so with .NET 7), in a rather flakey way, as one would expect considering the limitations of certain types of edits not being supported. But I'm talking about very simple edits, like changing <p>Hi</p> to <p>Bye</p> in a Razor component.
In my case, it got to the point where every attempt to apply edits via hot reload would result in VS encountering an "Unexpected error" (a ManagedDeltaApplierFailedToConnectException, to be precise) and post the following dialog box:

In other words, Hot Reload is completely broken. What is the fix?

the same here, started noticing after the latest VS update and wasm workload update

In the index.html file of your client project, inside the <body> tag, near the bottom with the other script tags, add the following
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script>
</environment>

Then,

Close down the client (browser) and server (if using hosted)
Restart VS
Build your solution
Run it (CTRL-F5)
Make a simple HMTL edit
Apply hot reload (ALT-F10) and watch with delight as your edits are applied without the irritating error dialog appearing.


it helps. Thanks! BTW did not work w/o re-strarting Visual Studio, must to take step. Also I did not have index.html which must be "WASM-only" project, I had mix of server and client project and added the script to the body section of App.razor

I just get "No code changes were found" about 70% of the time

Plus all sorts of namespace invalid errors that refer to the csproj file - these are false positives (the namespace does exist) and the location is wrong too as there's no namespaces in the csproj. It's pretty fragile even after all these years
